# Can't create SESSION

Tags: php, json, session

```
<?php
    ob_start();
    session_start();
    require ('openid.php');

    function logout() {
        echo '<form action="logout.php" method="post"><button class="btn btn-danger" type="submit"><i class="fa fa-power-off"></i> Log Out</button></form>'; //logout button
    }

    function steamlogin() {
        try {
            require("settings.php");
            $openid = new LightOpenID($domain);

            if(!$openid->mode) {
                if(isset($_GET['login'])) {
                    $openid->identity = 'http://steamcommunity.com/openid';
                    header('Location: ' . $openid->authUrl());
                }

            return "<form action=\"?login\" method=\"post\"> <input type=\"image\" src=\"http://cdn.steamcommunity.com/public/images/signinthroughsteam/sits_large_noborder.png\"></form>";
            }

             elseif($openid->mode == 'cancel') {
                echo 'User has canceled authentication!';
            } else {
                if($openid->validate()) {
                        $id = $openid->identity;
                        $ptn = "/^http:\/\/steamcommunity\.com\/openid\/id\/(7[0-9]{15,25}+)$/";
                        preg_match($ptn, $id, $matches);

                        $steamid = $matches[1];

                                        $link = file_get_contents("http://api.steampowered.com/ISteamUser/GetPlayerSummaries/v0002/?key=".$key."&steamids=".$steamid."");
                                        $decode = json_decode($link);
                                        $newlink = $decode->response->players->profileurl;
                                        $xml = simplexml_load_file($newlink."?xml=1");
                                        @$custom = $xml->customURL;
                                        if(strlen($custom) <= 4){      
                                                $user = $xml->steamID64;
                                        } else {
                                                $user = $custom;
                                        }      
                                        $_SESSION['steamid'] = $user;

                        //Determine the return to page. We substract "login&"" to remove the login var from the URL.
                        //"file.php?login&foo=bar" would become "file.php?foo=bar"
                        $returnTo = str_replace('login&', '', $_GET['openid_return_to']);
                        //If it didn't change anything, it means that there's no additionals vars, so remove the login var so that we don't get redirected to Steam over and over.
                        if($returnTo === $_GET['openid_return_to']) $returnTo = str_replace('?login', '', $_GET['openid_return_to']);
                        header('Location: '.$returnTo);
                } else {
                        echo "User is not logged in.\n";
                }

            }
        } catch(ErrorException $e) {
            echo $e->getMessage();
        }
    }
```

I checked this code 10 times (atleast) , but i don't understand why it doesn't create `$_SESSION['steamid']` . Can you help me ?

I edited first post !

Comment: did you use session_start() ?

Comment: Don't use `@` to suppress errors while you are developing and testing. You want to see errors.

Comment: Yes. First row after includes ...

Comment: please show us the rest of the file, but my best bet: some output (e.g. newline at the end of the file) in one of the includes

Comment: @usandfriends not only when you are developing, you should never suppress errors.

Comment: I added code on pastebin. Check first post ! Thank you !

Comment: @GeorgeCristian I suggest copying the code directly to your post...

Comment: I tried, but i get that error: "It looks like you past mostly code here" (or something like that)

Comment: are you getting anything in $user and why is this   @$custom = $xml->customURL;

Comment: Yes, i get all the time. $custom is set to some users, but not at all. So, i need @ there.

Comment: switch the two lines around
`session_start();` and `require ('openid.php');`

Answer (score 0):

First off, you should try setting dummy data to test if your session is working at all. Right after your `session_start()` put a line like

```
$_SESSION['test'] = 'test';
var_dump($_SESSION);
```

If the key does not persist throughout requests then it means there is a problem with your session handler (possibly lacking write permission).

If your session is working then you start going down the tree of logic, check the expressions in each if statement to see what the execution path is, you do not provide any current output so I cannot tell right away.

This is not a definitive answer but I'm sure if you follow my advice you'll get to the root of the problem.

Comment: @GeorgeCristian there are a number of reasons why sessions might not be working. By far the most common one is lack of write permissions IMO. Find the location where sessions are being stored either by session_save_path() or in php.ini and check it's permissions. Other reasons may include disabled cookies in browser, attempting to share sessions across domains, wrong cookie path and many more.